# Remove All Linux Users for Next Computer Owner

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have some computers running Linux Mint 18.3 Mate that have a single user account set up on them which will soon have new owners. There is no personal information on the hard drives (they were thoroughly wiped before installing Mint and have not been used except for updating). I would like to delete the existing user account and have the computer prompt the new owner to set up their user account. I have seen this done when I volunteered for a computer restoration organization, but I don't remember how they accomplished it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably simply reinstall using the "OEM Installer" option.  This leaves things ready for a First Boot Set Up experience...

Note - I've never actually needed/used it, but I've seen it on the boot options menu for so long ...

If that won't work for some reason (ie, you've spent a lot of time setting up a dev environment, etc) then you can check the list of users (any user w/ UID over 999) in `/etc/passwd` and then use the `deluser` command on them.  Be sure to delete their home directories, etc.

I would recommend immediately adding a new user and giving that user `sudo` access by placing them in the appropriate group (`sudo` or `admin` IIRC) or by editing the `/etc/sudoers` file via `visudo` and making the required changes there.

Comment: I didn't see that option. I guess I can reinstall.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/36671/how-do-i-pre-install-ubuntu-for-someone-oem-install